# Submit no teclado numérico - Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

Olá.
Estou com dificuldades para usar o submit em um input numérico no Intel XDK.
Quero que ao clicar no "GO/IR" , execute uma função.

No JS está assim:

`$('ins_prod').on('submit', function(){ 
   alert("oi");
 });`

Só que ao executar ele reseta a aplicação.

Comment: Você pode obter qual é o key code quando clicar em "GO/IR" [aqui](http://keycode.info/). Se puder compartilhar conosco, ajudaria.

Comment: Opa @Lucas Costa, cara acessei o site pelo dispositivo mas ele não ativou o teclado. Estou deixando de fazer algo?

Comment: Não sei dizer, não conheço Intel XDK, meu palpite era que essa tecla poderia estar sendo reconhecida com um key code diferente.

Comment: Localizei um outro site com a mesma finalidade, deu Keycode 13 (enter)

Comment: Consegui solucionar. Mas após a execução da função (no exemplo o alert) ainda está resetando o aplicativo.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Acima do alert, tenta colocar `preventDefault`. Ficaria assim: `$('ins_prod').on('submit', function(ev){ ev.preventDefault();  
   alert("oi");
 });`

Comment: meu código ficou assim:
`$('#ins_prod').on('keydown',function(i){
    if (i.keyCode == 13){
         i.preventDefaut();
         alert("oi");
     }
});`

mesmo assim, após a execução do alerta, reseta o app.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido:
O input estava dentro de um form. Removi e o erro de resetar o app, parou.
Vlw pela força.